# Can I make my github pages repository private and still have the web link itself be public and indexed by search engines?

Tags: github, search, jekyll, github-pages

I have a github page, username.github.io. I'd like to make the webpage itself public so everyone can see it and it will be picked up by Google search, but I'd like to have the repository where I make the changes itself private (github.com/username/username.github.io).

Also, there is a nuance between the webpage appearing and search engines finding it: Even if the repository is private, the webpage itself is public (username.github.io goes to a link) and will work. However, Google/other search engines can't find it.

Is it possible to have my repository private and still have Google find it?

Comment: what do you mean by "google to find it"; as far as i understand, do you want your site to be public but not your github repository ?

Answer (score 1):

With paid plans, your GitHub Pages repository can be private, otherwise it needs to be public. ([Reference](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages)).

Having the repository private does not prevent search engines from finding it. If it is not picked up automatically, you can manually ask Google to index your web page by creating an account with [Google Search Console](https://search.google.com/search-console/about) and submitting your website.